# PatternFill from Openpyxl doesn't work as intended

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have some trouble with openpyxl. It crashes when trying to save a file. Example below:

```py
import openpyxl

fp=r'c:\\path to\\file.xlsx'
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(fp)
ws1=wb['Sheet name']
pat_fil=openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType="solid", fgColor="00800080")
ws1["A2"].fill=pat_fil
wb.save("name.xlsx")
```

Any idea what to do?

```
Error:
Type error: expected<class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

It doesn't work with `pat_fil=openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType="solid", start_color="00800080", end_color="00800080")` or with `pat_fil=openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType="solid", start_color="800080", end_color="800080")`
I also tried to downgrade to version 2.5.4, but the error is the same. I'm working with Microsoft 365 if this might help

Comment: I'd think you'd get a syntax error with this line `ws1["A2'].fill=pat_fil` but otherwise should be OK.

Comment: Does that cell have any existing fill applied? Your code works with a blank workbook.

Comment: Your MS Office version should have no impact since it has no affect on the python code.

Comment: The error `Type error: expected<class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>` is more likely something you would see when loading a file so seems possible its the loading of your xlsx file that is causing this error and nothing to do with the PatternFill. Try another workbook.

Comment: @moken the only syntax error is when saving. Also, in the document there are some other data, but nothing to affect the cells i want to fill. I've tried with a blank workbook to test out some functions and i confirm it's working just fine. The problem seems to be with the file i want to load. The file itself contains only some dataframes that have nothing to do with the cells i want to format

Comment: `ws1["A2']` should give an error, you have a double quote closed with a single quote. Maybe an error in the copying. Anyway just try opening your xlsx file in Excel then save it (not just close but actually select save then close). Try your code again on the resaved file.

Comment: I've tried that too and has the same result. I'm working with generated files (by the python script i'm writing) and this solution doesn't seems too practical, mosly because if the ```wb.save("filename.xlsx")``` crashes, the file appears as corrupted, so even if the manual save would work, i'd need a solution that would solve this trough code

Comment: Ultimately there is a problem with your xlsx file(s). Maybe it could be "cleaned" up by opening and resaving but from your response that appear to be a negative. So you can try another module like Xlwings or look at your code that produces the file and try to determine where the issue is that's causing the problem. Obviously we cannot reproduce so cannot provide much more of an insight into exactly what is causing it in your files and the best option to fix.

Comment: I've taken your advice and tried to replace openpyxl with xlwings anad, while xlwings appears slower, it helped me figure out the problem. The problem is from one drive: It doesn't allow multiple modifications in short succession and, when xlwings tries to open the file, it's prompted with the "save a copy" screen, with which it doesn't know what to do. But, if i pause the script, resave manually, then, the script does it's job as intended.